# postgres round function: unexpected behaviour in specific query

Tags: postgresql, postgis, rounding

This simple postgres round call rounds the numeric to 3 decimal places, as expected:

```
SELECT round(43.1235421,3);
 round  
--------
 43.124
(1 row)
```

However, the exact same round operation in the query below gives me `43.1240000000000023`. The query is run against a postgis database, in case that makes a difference.

```
(SELECT ogc_fid,wkb_geometry,round(43.1235421,3) AS lat FROM grid_1) AS "grid"
```

This behaviour is undesired. What am I doing wrong? How can I get a float rounded to 3 decimal places, as expected? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I tried explicitly casting the float as a numeric in the postgis query, but got the same result.

```
(SELECT ogc_fid,wkb_geometry,round(43.1235421::numeric,3) AS lat FROM grid_1) AS "grid"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both give the same answer, the postgis one just gives more decimal places in the result, and some of them are worthless.  floats are rarely precise, there are only a few fractions that have precise binary representations and 0.2 isn't one of them. if you extend the result to enough places you'll start to see the inprecision.

if you need base-10 precision use numeric instead of float.

if you still want floats, but want to hide the ugly part

```
 SET extra_float_digits TO 0;
```

Comment: Casting to numeric gives me the same ugly "floats" for almost all input values, and turns out the mapping software (Tilemill) doesn't let me run a SET before the actual query. Is there any other way to just get the standard `round()` behaviour in a postgis db?

Comment: I mean _use_ numeric, not cast the result. although casting fo a fixed-width numeric would work too. `select 43.1235421::numeric(6,3);`